# PCL Project Phoneword in Xamarin.Forms build failed

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I decided to start my adventure with Xamarin.Forms .
I had project called Phoneword from this link https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/getting-started/hello-xamarin-forms/quickstart/ on win 8.1.
After update to win10 problems occured...

I did clean install of VS and Xamarin. Working on 2.0 Xamarin.Forms .
All steps from guide done correctly.

My problems:

In App.cs System is highlighted as unnecessary and Phoneword as "not found" in line "MainPage = new Phoneword.MainPage ();".

In MainPage.xaml.cs System.Threading.Tasks highlighted as unnecessary and sometimes InitializeComponents() and objects get errors "not found".

In IDialer.cs System highlighted as unnecessary.

In PhoneDialer.cs included in platform projects IDialer is not visible as interface, just highlighted as not found.

Lenovo B570e
Clean already installed Win 10 Pro lite version of polish group SLT
Xamarin 4.0+ version
Forms 2.0, after update to 2.2 failed uninstalling 2.0, restart VS and 2.2 seems like updated

Hope some of us can help here

Comment: Could you zip up the project as it exists on your end and upload it to Dropbox/OneDrive or something of the sort to test? I'm wondering if something is going on with your project settings or if some things aren't installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED
Need to do simply Windows Update and ADDITIONAL UPDATE of all .NET packages.
Then reinstall VS and Xamarin. 
Clean project, when InitializeComponent() crashes, change x:Class in any other name XAML, save and restart VS.
Restore x:Class to correct form, save and restart.
Then build and everything works.
Spent up to 70hrs trying to solve it by other posts about Xamarin build problem, but the best solution is independently work.